# Service windows and Async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, service

I am pretty new to windows service and I am trying to install a service to run some code (that I did not write).
This code runs without problem ( not in service mode) but when I install the service and try to run the service I have a timeout Error 1053 (The Service did not Respond to the Start or Control Request in a Timely Fashion).

I tried to set the `ServicePipeTimeout` to a higher value and install my service in release mode but that does not change anything.

After some investigations and prints I get an error with the main function Static Async Task()
So I am asking myself if maybe there is an incompatibility between Async and service ?

For example Maybe this kind of code executed at the beginning, could provoke timeout I get when I start my service: (I just wanted to know if async and service was compatible to help me in my search).

```
static void Main(string[] _)
{
    MainAsync().Wait(); 
}

private static async Task MainAsync()
{
    TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    using (SftpWatcher watcher = new SftpWatcher(mailServer, mailSender, mailName, mailDestination, ...)
    {
        await watcher.Start(timeSpan);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add some code. All we know about your project is what you write in the question.

Comment: BTW: If the service start runs into a timeout, increasing the timeout is in 99.9% of the cases not a solution.

Comment: *"If the service start runs into a timeout, increasing the timeout is in 99.9% of the cases not a solution."* -- @Fildor may I ask where you got this 99.9% statistic? Is it from personal experience or what?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I pulled it completely out of my nose. :D So, personal experience, yes. Of course, there may be cases, where it helps. Just haven't seen one in years or here on SO. Most of the time people just were doing something in Start that they were not supposed to.

Comment: i cannot put more code to explain, I looking something to dig to find a solution :) I just cannot explain difference between run well in .exe mode but not in service mode

Comment: @Fildor np. I am just amazed/entertained every time people throw statistics with multiple 9s, because these numbers imply a sample space of totally unrealistic size. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah, I know what you are talking about. Of course, I wasn't particularly serious about the number.

Comment: _"MainAsync().Wait();"_ Wait what? I guess, you already may have a deadlock, here.

Comment: What Framework / Version are we talking about?

Comment: This wait the end of the MainAsync() method, who instantiate a watcher to check files in SFTP repo. but yeah i think i am stuck here.

Comment: What project is SftpWatcher from? Is it something you wrote or 3rd Party?

Comment: Using .NET 4.7.2

Comment: 3rd party i had to convert this projet to a service.

Comment: So, that's .NET Framework 4.7.2, where - I guess - there is no `async Task Main` possible, right?

Comment: I haven't been dealing with such ancient versions in a while. I am trying to think of something, that will make it possible to use async API ... but everything I can come up with is ... "not recommended".

Comment: Async Task Main is not allowed in 4.7.2 ? i dont think so, because this part work very well without service and still using 4.7.2

Comment: ok i see maybe this is the cause of deadlock. i should rewrite code to remove the async task, i dont thinks this is very important for this kind of service.

Comment: Yes, async Main was part of C# 7.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main - not sure what framework version corresponds to that.

Comment: C# 7.3 released with .NET 4.7.2.  This would work normally

Comment: In that case you should be able to make it `public static async Task Main()` and await the MainAsync. That_should_ at least prevent a deadlock. - IF that was a problem in the first place.

Comment: Please post your actual Win32 service code that duplicates the problem. I don't see any `ServiceBase` or anything like that in your code.